# calculating simple moving average and insert into sql table

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1364

I want to calculate a simple moving average
and insert it into the table

Table (Kaffee)
Columns are Datum (for date) and price and sma20 (which is empty and must be filled)

| Datum | Price | sma20 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1973-09-05 | 0.64 | 0.00 |
| 1973-09-06 | 0.66 | 0.00 |
| 1973-09-07 | 0.69 | 0.00 |

When I try this

```
Insert into kaffee(sma20)
select avg(price) OVER(
   ORDER BY datum ROWS BETWEEN 20 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) 
from kaffee;
```

It gives the following error:

> #1364 - 'datum' doesn't have a default values

When is just start the select query its working fine.

Does anyone has a solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Use an `UPDATE` statement in place of the `INSERT` one. You can exploit the "*Datum*" field to match the subquery and original table:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Datum,
           AVG(price) OVER(
               ORDER BY datum 
               ROWS BETWEEN 20 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS average 
    FROM kaffee
)
UPDATE     kaffee
INNER JOIN cte
        ON kaffee.Datum = cte.Datum
SET sma20 = cte.average;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mGonaMABrkySgh9NfiZhzf/0).